# Как организовать наследование в php

Tags: php, ооп

Обычный традиционный способ наследования подразумевает простую иерархию например:

```
class A { 
    public function func_a() {
        echo 'work!';
    } 
}

class B extends A { 

   public function func_b () {
       echo 'work B!';
   }
}

class C extends A { 

   public function func_c () {
       echo 'work C!';
   }
}

$C = new C();
$C->func();
$C->func_c();
```

Так делают обычно, а мне нужно сделать так что-бы можно было из одного класса вызывать множество других. Например :

```
$A = new A();
$A->func_c();
$A->func_b();
$A->func_a();
```

Вот как мне реализовать такой подход, при этом мне нужно расширять функциональность класса А от других классов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Альтернативой могут быть трейты или что-то самописное на основе магических методов.

Начиная с версии 5.4.0 PHP вводит инструментарий для повторного использования кода, называемый трейтом.

Трейты предназначены для уменьшения некоторых ограничений единого наследования, позволяя разработчику повторно использовать наборы методов свободно, в нескольких независимых классах и реализованных с использованием разных архитектур построения классов. Семантика комбинации трейтов и классов определена таким образом, чтобы снизить уровень сложности, а также избежать типичных проблем, связанных с множественным наследованием и c т.н. mixins.

Трейт очень похож на класс, но предназначен для группирования функционала хорошо структурированным и последовательным образом. Невозможно создать самостоятельный экземпляр трейта. Это дополнение к обычному наследованию и позволяет сделать горизонтальную композицию поведения, то есть применение членов класса без необходимости наследования.

Несколько трейтов могут быть вставлены в класс путем их перечисления в директиве use, разделяя запятыми.

Пример использования нескольких трейтов

```
<?php
trait Hello {
    public function sayHello() {
        echo 'Hello ';
    }
}

trait World {
    public function sayWorld() {
        echo 'World';
    }
}

class MyHelloWorld {
    use Hello, World;
    public function sayExclamationMark() {
        echo '!';
    }
}

$o = new MyHelloWorld();
$o->sayHello();
$o->sayWorld();
$o->sayExclamationMark();
?>
```

Результат выполнения данного примера:

```
Hello World!
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.traits.php